# Notepad++ pass a keyboard shortcut from command line

Tags: notepad++

I frequently open files in Notepad++ from the command line. Is there a way to pass an argument that collapses the Nth code block(s)? For instance, open a file and collapse the 1st, 2nd and 5th code blocks that are Level 1 blocks.

If this is not possible with Notepad++ is there another lightweight editor that might offer this from the command line? I have searched the docs and SO extensively but I do not see an option.

Comment: can you give an example of what you mean by Nth code block?

Comment: I gave an example in the original post. It's the sentence right after the word "Nth" that starts with "For instance..."